# Unable to add VM Switch: Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual switch with name

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-core

I messed up our host running Core 2022.  I can ping the server but can't connect to anything and the server can't communicate out either.  I have no idea what is wrong however Hyper-V has been tied to the issue.  There was a vm switch present when I reset the NICs after which the vm swtich has disappeared.  I cannot add a new switch.  When I run the command `add-vmswitch server` and add a resource group name, it comes back with an error `Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual switch with name "server"`.  This makes no sense to me.  Am I doing something wrong in my command?  Why am I getting this error?  Google has 0 results.